# Recursive Addition PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I am asked to make a recursive addition of a passes value for example if the value passes is 1024 i should get the answer 7

I am using this code

```
function recursiveAdd($arg)
{
    $ans = floor($arg);
    if ($arg<=1) return $ans;
    if (($arg/10)>0) return $ans + floor(recursiveAdd($arg/10));
    //else return $arg % 10;
}

echo recursiveAdd(1024);
```

I think i am there, if i run it i get 1137 in this case the last number is what i need.

Can you please check it as i think i am not seeing the wrong recursion!

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one does what is requested and is a bit simplified:

```
<?php
function recursiveAdd($arg)
{
    if ($arg>9) {
        return $arg%10 + recursiveAdd(floor($arg/10));
    } else {
        return $arg;
    }
}

echo recursiveAdd(1024);
```

However you don't have to use recursion, things are faster and less resource hungry without:

```
<?php
function sequentialAdd($arg)
{
    $sum = 0;
    $string = (string) $arg;
    foreach (str_split($string) as $digit) {
        $sum += $digit;
    }
    return $sum;
}

echo sequentialAdd(1024);
```

Comment: This works perfectly seems! Getting voted as answer thanks very much!

Comment: I know I know it is simpler this way but the function actually is to be used for other reasons and it has to be recursive! Thanks for the updated answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can Try this without recursion

```
function recursiveAdd($arg)
{
    $ans=0;
    $i=$arg%10;
    while($arg>0)
    {
       $ans+=$i;
       $arg=$arg/10;
    }
    return $ans;
}
```

Comment: where is recursion here ?

Comment: No this actually is not a recursion is an iteration and it doesnt work :/